# Delete option is not working in javascript createelement?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
  document.getElementById("add_image").onclick=function (ev) {

    var image=document.getElementById("images");

    var preview=document.createElement("img");
    preview.style.width="auto";
    preview.style.height="100px";


    var newInput=document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type="file";
    newInput.name="file[]";
    var delbutton = document.createElement("button")
    delbutton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete"));


    var br=document.createElement("br");
    var br1=document.createElement("br");

    newInput.onchange=function (ev1) {
      if(this.files && this.files[0]){
          var fileReader=new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload=function (ev2) {
              preview.src=ev2.target.result;
          };

          fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0])
      }
    };

    image.appendChild(preview);
    image.appendChild(delbutton);
    image.appendChild(newInput);
    image.appendChild(br);
    image.appendChild(br1);

  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Add Product</h1>
  <input type="text"><br><br>
        <div id="images">
          <input type="file" name="file[]"><br><br>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="add_image">+Add Image</button><br><br>

</div>
```

Here, The user will upload images of how many they want and whenever they need. If they don't need and click the delete button that the last file only deleted. I need to delete the last fileinput field whenever I click the delete button. I am not including that yet.

Comment: _"Delete option is not working..."_ - Because your script doesn't even try to delete anything... -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: `var btn = document.createElement("button");  
          var t = document.createTextNode("Delete"); 
          btn.appendChild(t);  btn.onclick = function(){myFunction(myparameter)};  
        document.getElementById("add_image").removeChild(btn); ` This is i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `addEventListener` method on `delButton` and Listen to `click` event, So that when button is clicked, you could delete `delbutton` ( being the target element that is clicked), `preview` (previus sibling elemnt of delButton), and `newInput` (next sibling element of delButton) using `.remove()` method. just use `.remove()` method on whatever element you want to delete when click event on delButton is run.

You may like to learn more about J[avaScript event listeners](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javascript-event-listeners--cms-35236).

Below is an example:

```js
document.getElementById("add_image").onclick=function (ev) {

    var image=document.getElementById("images");

    var preview=document.createElement("img");
    preview.style.width="auto";
    preview.style.height="100px";


    var newInput=document.createElement("input");
    newInput.type="file";
    newInput.name="file[]";
    var delbutton = document.createElement("button")
    delbutton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete"));


    var br=document.createElement("br");
    var br1=document.createElement("br");

    newInput.onchange=function (ev1) {
      if(this.files && this.files[0]){
          var fileReader=new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload=function (ev2) {
              preview.src=ev2.target.result;
          };

          fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0])
      }
    };

    image.appendChild(preview);
    image.appendChild(delbutton);
    image.appendChild(newInput);
    image.appendChild(br);
    image.appendChild(br1);
    
 //Follow is the answer
delbutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.target.previousSibling.remove();
    event.target.nextSibling.remove();
    event.target.remove();
});

 }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Add Product</h1>
  <input type="text"><br><br>
        <div id="images">
          <input type="file" name="file[]"><br><br>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="add_image">+Add Image</button><br><br>

</div>
```